Error of Ionic Capacitor - Unable to open asset url - https://localhost/src/index.jsx
So basically I'm facing this error from pas 2 hours. I tried editing capacitor.config.ts in my project as well as capacitor.config.json in android assets folder and many other ways. But nothing seems to work also my project is a web app made using react vite and firebase. I built all the files and then opened android studio to test it built the gradle properly but gives this error and the app doesn't work on device simulator. Here are some of the screenshots for reference.
Here is my capacitor.config.ts code
import type { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli`;

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.mealconnect.app',
  appName: 'MealConnect',
  webDir: 'dist',
  "android": {
    "allowMixedContent": true
  },
  "server": {
    "cleartext": true,
    "hostname": "localhost"
  }
};



export default config;

Also here's my capacitor.config.json code
    "appId": "com.mealconnect.app",
    "appName": "MealConnect",
    "webDir": "dist",
    "android": {
        "allowMixedContent": true
    },
    "server": {
        "cleartext": true,
        "hostname": "localhost"
    }
}

I tried adding some stackoverflow ans still didn't work. Moved files rebuilt it few times by changing the path still didn't work
